# Google Maps Markers disappear at certain zoom level only on iPhone/iPad

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am really stuck at the moment with a very strange problem using the Google Maps API V3.

I have a map in an iframe that shows a lot of markers with some custom infoboxes for each on click, here:

http://www.whist.ch/karte

Everything works fine on all browsers I have tested on Mac and PC (Chrome, Firefox, IE). On the iPad and iPhone however the markers disappear when zoomed in too close and reappear again when zooming out.

Does anyone have an explanation or fix for this?

Much appreciated,

Armin.

ps. there is also some ugly white lines in Google Maps on iPad, maybe someone knows how to get rid of those too :)

Comment: Did you try Safari on Mac? I just did and the markers didn't even show up at all, at any time.

Answer (score 7):

After a lot of intense debugging, I think I found a solution to my problem (maybe yours too).  It also seems Google is aware of the problem, and that's how I figured out a solution.  I used an awesome debugger called [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/) ([documentation](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/)), it's a remote debugging utility for webkit based browsers.

The Google Maps API uses the `-webkit-transform: matrix(a,b,c,d,f);` CSS property to do pinch-zoom and panning.  It's all very pretty, but it seems there is a bug on webkit based browsers on the iPad (I tried three other browsers, not just Safari).  I noticed that many (if not most) div elements that were placed in the map for map tiles, overlays, shadows, etc all had `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);` applied.  I added that line to my `img` and `div` elements and instantly fixed my problem.

I haven't tried it by adding the style through a linked stylesheet, only by modifying each element directly, but there you go; a solution:

```
element.style.webkitTransform = "-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);";
```

**tl;dr it's iPad bug... to solve add** `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);` **to anything that disappears.**

Comment: Safari 6.0.4 on Mac had some marker distortion issues and the same fix also worked for this case.

Comment: Thank you so much, this just took me too long to discover, very annoying that its not visible why they dissapear. Thanks once again.

Comment: Hallelujah! I had various map elements disappearing (including google's own logo and Ts&Cs) when scrolling an embedded google map on iOS safari. This has allowed me to fix the important elements (my own controls and overlays).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to confirm that the -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px) reset solves the issue. I see this as more of an issue with Google's InfoBox plugin, though.

My fix updates the InfoBox script(v1.1.11) as follows:

In InfoBox.prototype.setBoxStyle_ :

```
// Apply style values defined in the boxStyle parameter:
boxStyle = this.boxStyle_;
for (i in boxStyle) {
  if (boxStyle.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    this.div_.style[i] = boxStyle[i];
  }
}
//Fix for iOS dissappearing InfoBox
if (typeof this.div_.style.webkitTransform === 'undefined') this.div_.style.webkitTransform = 'translateZ(0px)';

// Fix up opacity style for benefit of MSIE:
```

Comment: i was also seeing this problem but only with my InfoBoxes

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem in `Chrome Version 51.0.2704.84`. When I used different marker types and get max zoom, markers disappeared.

This solution helped me:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
```